# How do I ask spotless gradle plugin to skip licenseHeader check

Tags: java, gradle, spotless

How do I ask spotless gradle plugin with google formatter to skip licenseHeader check, I use a different plugin to format my license headers and this is making corrections to those headers which I want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove `<licenseHeader>` and it works for me.

Haven't seen any documentation about it.